# Delete all files from list of folders on server A and then copy all files from same list of folders from server B

Tags: windows, batch

I need to remove all files from a list of folders on Server A and then copy all the contents from the same list of folders from Server B. What is the easiest way to loop through the list and complete this action?

Comment: Are you talking about Server A having a backup of Server B and Server B needs to periodically re-write Server A?

Comment: Sort of...it is more like moving up files to a different testing environment. So once the testing is complete in Server B we want to move it up to the Server A environment for testing there. We want to wipe out the old version and put what Server B has.

Answer (score 0):

If your using a Windows environment you can look at using Robocopy with the /MIR switch.

It will mirror server B to server A.  You will also save time since it will only copy new and modified files only while deleting anything that no longer exists.

Just make sure you dont get the command backwards or you can end up mirroring an empty drive.

Comment: This may be a possibility...The only problem is, I dont always want every folder updated. Sometimes there are specific folders that do need to be changed and the rest need to remain unchanged because that version is not ready to be tested. That is where the list comes in. I'm just looking for a way to select which folders I want copied and which folders I dont. Right now I just have a bat file with about 30 folders hardcoded to delete the contents and then copy and it is annoying to comment out the ones that dont need to be updated every time.